# Aftermarket radio problem

Tags: electrical, audio, mercedes-benz

I self-installed a Kenwood DNX4230BT Headunit into a 2003 Mercedes clk with stock factory speakers. Before I installed the Kenwood the audio was crystal clear and perfect with the wold merc Headunit, however now after I fitted the Kenwood the sound is not as clear as before. Mind you it can get loud etc however it is not as clear as before just lacking that Final "zing"
Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Check the wiring to your speakers. Ensure you have connected all the +/- correctly. If you have some +'s going to -'s, your speakers will be out of phase and may cause the issues you're talking about.

Comment: As it was done using a plug and play connects2 adaptor surely there no chance of an issue like this arising? Is there any easy way to check, I can easily remove radio as it isn't bolted in correctly anyway

Comment: I'm no audio expert, it's just one of the things I do know about it. All speakers have to be phased the same direction or it will sound *funny*. As for checking, most stereos I've installed have a plug with wires which goes to the head unit, then a second plug with wires which gets connected to the vehicle harness. These two plugs w/wires must be married. That's where something could get mixed up as I'm suggesting. If you have a different type of connector which does it all without the marrying aspect, that's golden.

Comment: Yeh I've got 2 points of "marrying" as connector goes into Headunit to a socket, where I plug in 2 connectors from the aftermarket steering interface which then goes to another socket to which we plug in the original vehicle interface. So it's entirely possible one or the other is wrong.

Comment: It's 2am here in the UK so I will check tomorrow and report back to you, maybe one of the plugs is in the opposite way? However its highly unlikely as he faded balance seems to work perfectly I.e move all sounds from left to right etc

Comment: Thanks very much by the way :) if anyone else has any other suggestions it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: What speaker impedance can the radio drive? What is the impedance of the factory speakers?

Comment: What's impendencd???

Comment: impedance issues would more likely manifest as a lack of volume or bass, not as missing highs.

Comment: Have you checked the equalizer settings on both the old and new systems? If the old system had its equalizer or tone controls (or loudness) set to provide a boost to high frequencies and the new system is set to a flat response, you can get the issue you describe.